# How to create an "Add Attachement" column in sharepoint 2010?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-designer, attachment

Googled and looked here for a while with no answer found so far.

I am currently trying to have a column work similar to the edit button. With the edit button you click the icon and you are redirected to the edit page. I want something the users can click to go straight to the add attachment section. It does not need to be a button, even though it would look nice. We also have designer so that is an option as well.

Any suggestions or link on how I can try to make this work? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: There is URL field type, so you can use it, just by adding column to the list. Also you can add button to the ribbon ot to the dropdown menu for element using CustomActions

Comment: Do you know how I would go about getting the url for an add attachment section? When I compare the attachment url to edit url they are the same.

Answer (score 0):

Could you not Create another ECB item just like the edit button with the name add attachment 
Pass the ID of the item via query string.
Pick this up in c# and work your magic to add an attachment?

This is how to create an ECB menu item

http://www.learningsharepoint.com/2012/05/22/add-custom-editcontrolblock-ecb-menu-item-to-open-a-custom-page-in-sharepoint/

Hope this helps

Cheers
      Truez

Comment: Thanks I will look into this today. Is this only possible in 2010?

Comment: I have done an ECB item in 2007, Never in 2010 but i would assume that this can be done.